# UIKit DrawRect (Bug?) flashing

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, draw

I have the following code, which is causing a weird flashing effect every time the timer fires. In its entirety:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
var runCounter = 0
class MyView: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if runCounter == 1 {
            UIColor.white.setFill()
            print(runCounter)  //debugging
            print(self.bounds) //debugging
            UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).fill()
        }
    }
}
let view = MyView()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1/5, repeats: true, block: {timer in 
    view.setNeedsDisplay()
    runCounter += 1
})
```

As you can see, this is causing a flashing effect, even though runCounter should only ever be set to 1 once. I'd expect it either to remain white forever, or to clear on the next call and remain black forever. I don't understand why this is happening. Is it a UIKit bug?

[image]

Comment: Which instance of `view` you are seeing the flashing? I hope it is `view.setNeedsDisplay`, right? And here you have `repeats: true`. What else you are expecting here?

Comment: But why would it go back and forth between the white background and nothing being drawn? RunCounter is never at 1 again. If calling drawRect clears the cached drawing it should turn black again forever.

Comment: This is fascinating. I recreated your issue using a view controller to instantiate the view, but got the same behaviour. I think that the issue relates to the contents property of the view's layer - print out a debugDescription of the layer's contents and you'll see that the backing store changes as you iterate through the loop (from one item to three). I wonder whether the drawing system is somehow cycling through this array giving you the flashing behaviour. Note also that if you set isOpaque to false the problem disappears. Input appreciated from anyone with better knowledge of CALayer!

Comment: Interesting. Setting isOpaque to false fixes the problem… but then setting clearsContextBeforeDrawing to also be false causes the problem to resurface. Maybe I should file a radar?